# Solar flares effects in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know how to recreate a figure like the one below taken from Wikipedia with Tikz (using Mathcha.io editor) with a few weeks of work. However... I'm not able to found a trick to reproduce to solar flares effect. Does anyone know how to do that or a workaround using purely tikz?

Thanks for help (feedback)

[image]

Here is what i have done so far with Mathcha.io (do the Sun interior won't be a problem but i can't found yet a good trick to make the solar flares realistic).

```
% Gradient Info
  
\tikzset {_t5fm1pwc6/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{ \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0 bp } { 0 bp }  }  \pgftransformscale{1 }  }}}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{_obsq0geoy}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{rgb(0bp)=(0.97,0.67,0.27);
rgb(0.08117079734802246bp)=(0.97,0.67,0.27);
rgb(25bp)=(1,1,1);
rgb(400bp)=(1,1,1)}

% Gradient Info
  
\tikzset {_iuwzyyncp/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{ \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0 bp } { 0 bp }  }  \pgftransformscale{1 }  }}}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{_kh4b0jmmf}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{rgb(0bp)=(0.97,0.67,0.27);
rgb(18.609733070646016bp)=(0.97,0.67,0.27);
rgb(25bp)=(1,1,1);
rgb(400bp)=(1,1,1)}
\tikzset{_pmbtb93xf/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0 bp } { 0 bp }  }  \pgftransformscale{1 } }}}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{_astx8j2w0} { \pgfpoint{0bp} {0bp}} {color(0bp)=(transparent!0);
color(18.609733070646016bp)=(transparent!0);
color(25bp)=(transparent!60);
color(400bp)=(transparent!60)} 
\pgfdeclarefading{_dtm1q1pyh}{\tikz \fill[shading=_astx8j2w0,_pmbtb93xf] (0,0) rectangle (50bp,50bp); } 
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,563); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 563

%Shape: Star [id:dp023212525835953457] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][shading=_obsq0geoy,_t5fm1pwc6] (312.74,-9.01) -- (324.39,116.79) -- (359.15,-4.48) -- (347.28,121.29) -- (403.88,8.93) -- (368.92,130.14) -- (445.31,30.75) -- (388.53,143.01) -- (481.96,60.18) -- (405.4,159.44) -- (512.49,96.17) -- (418.92,178.83) -- (535.8,137.4) -- (428.61,200.49) -- (551.05,182.4) -- (434.1,223.62) -- (557.68,229.53) -- (435.21,247.4) -- (555.46,277.09) -- (431.89,270.97) -- (544.47,323.36) -- (424.27,293.46) -- (525.1,366.67) -- (412.61,314.08) -- (498.06,405.45) -- (397.35,332.07) -- (464.32,438.31) -- (379.03,346.79) -- (425.11,464.05) -- (358.31,357.7) -- (381.83,481.75) -- (335.94,364.4) -- (336.05,490.76) -- (312.74,366.67) -- (289.43,490.76) -- (289.54,364.4) -- (243.65,481.75) -- (267.17,357.7) -- (200.37,464.05) -- (246.45,346.79) -- (161.16,438.31) -- (228.13,332.07) -- (127.42,405.45) -- (212.87,314.08) -- (100.37,366.67) -- (201.21,293.46) -- (81.01,323.36) -- (193.59,270.97) -- (70.02,277.09) -- (190.27,247.4) -- (67.8,229.53) -- (191.38,223.62) -- (74.43,182.4) -- (196.87,200.49) -- (89.68,137.4) -- (206.56,178.83) -- (112.99,96.17) -- (220.08,159.44) -- (143.52,60.18) -- (236.95,143.01) -- (180.16,30.75) -- (256.56,130.14) -- (221.6,8.93) -- (278.2,121.29) -- (266.33,-4.48) -- (301.08,116.79) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp6728583001635919] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][shading=_kh4b0jmmf,_iuwzyyncp,path fading= _dtm1q1pyh ,fading transform={xshift=2}] (164.36,228.64) .. controls (164.36,148.01) and (229.73,82.64) .. (310.36,82.64) .. controls (390.99,82.64) and (456.36,148.01) .. (456.36,228.64) .. controls (456.36,309.27) and (390.99,374.64) .. (310.36,374.64) .. controls (229.73,374.64) and (164.36,309.27) .. (164.36,228.64) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp9879493462214302] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 248; green, 171; blue, 70 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (180.72,228.64) .. controls (180.72,157.04) and (238.76,99) .. (310.36,99) .. controls (381.96,99) and (440,157.04) .. (440,228.64) .. controls (440,300.24) and (381.96,358.28) .. (310.36,358.28) .. controls (238.76,358.28) and (180.72,300.24) .. (180.72,228.64) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp27943444307429344] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 182; green, 77; blue, 32 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (270.29,118.5) .. controls (283.24,113.19) and (297.27,110.3) .. (311.91,110.3) .. controls (367.35,110.3) and (413.93,151.84) .. (427.15,208.06) -- (311.91,240.7) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp26161119443463554] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 152; green, 80; blue, 45 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (203.15,271.05) .. controls (201.19,261.3) and (200.15,251.13) .. (200.15,240.67) .. controls (200.15,185.08) and (229.57,137.55) .. (271.13,118.4) -- (311.95,240.67) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Chord [id:dp35742807417325095] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 140; green, 48; blue, 12 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (427.15,208.06) .. controls (427.28,208.37) and (427.38,208.67) .. (427.47,208.99) .. controls (432.17,225.59) and (385.83,253.25) .. (323.96,270.76) .. controls (262.09,288.26) and (208.12,288.99) .. (203.42,272.39) .. controls (203.3,271.95) and (203.21,271.5) .. (203.15,271.05) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp7799037211043129] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 250; green, 189; blue, 54 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (281.07,142.83) .. controls (290.74,139.17) and (301.11,137.19) .. (311.91,137.19) .. controls (355.92,137.19) and (392.89,170.16) .. (403.39,214.79) -- (311.91,240.7) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp34879155552294594] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 238; green, 246; blue, 123 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (296.83,196.41) .. controls (301.52,194.49) and (306.6,193.44) .. (311.91,193.44) .. controls (331.5,193.44) and (348.04,207.75) .. (353.29,227.35) -- (311.91,240.7) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp012569297105571309] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 235; green, 132; blue, 35 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (209.23,269.18) .. controls (207.61,259.99) and (206.76,250.43) .. (206.76,240.63) .. controls (206.76,185.99) and (233.25,139.13) .. (270.97,119.22) -- (311.5,240.63) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp27427186754084887] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 141; green, 47; blue, 15 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (259.9,256.51) .. controls (238.59,189.42) and (244.28,127.91) .. (272.86,118.63) .. controls (272.97,118.6) and (273.09,118.56) .. (273.2,118.52) -- (312.74,241.44) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp10266483730727005] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 139; blue, 28 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (299,273.59) .. controls (294.47,263.76) and (290.12,252.85) .. (286.21,241.21) .. controls (269.58,191.8) and (267.03,148.06) .. (280.51,143.52) .. controls (280.88,143.4) and (281.25,143.31) .. (281.63,143.24) -- (310.62,233) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp5993089550279873] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 139; blue, 28 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (403.18,214.89) .. controls (399.67,230.11) and (364.02,252.4) .. (317.31,267.57) .. controls (311.62,269.42) and (306.01,271.08) .. (300.51,272.56) -- (308.53,240.54) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp5876965449293687] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 180; green, 182; blue, 92 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (353.22,228.84) .. controls (354.17,239.23) and (339.55,252.3) .. (318.83,259.03) .. controls (313.73,260.68) and (308.7,261.81) .. (303.94,262.44) -- (312.56,239.7) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp6120653756991667] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 180; green, 182; blue, 92 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (301.89,263.57) .. controls (298.6,258.11) and (295.64,251.61) .. (293.31,244.45) .. controls (285.76,221.19) and (287.84,199.68) .. (297.95,196.4) .. controls (298.18,196.32) and (298.42,196.25) .. (298.66,196.2) -- (311.62,238.5) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da2375618727418527] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 141; green, 47; blue, 15 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (427.15,208.06) -- (311.66,239.32) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da43833166976470306] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 141; green, 47; blue, 15 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (298.07,275.94) -- (311.82,238.94) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8168641814227142] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 141; green, 47; blue, 15 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (273.2,118.52) -- (312.32,239.44) ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp3584215499566077] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 235; green, 132; blue, 35 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (266.03,275.12) .. controls (263.82,275.18) and (261.59,275.21) .. (259.33,275.21) .. controls (239.28,275.21) and (221.16,272.87) .. (208.13,269.11) -- (259.33,254.81) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives actually something childish:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a compilable excerpt of your solar flares trial? Thank you

Comment: This site is not a design office. :-) So propose something, and some `TikZ` experts will start to help you.

Comment: @MS-SPO just did it

Comment: Thank you. So that‘s just a sketch of the corona, right? Any flare attempts made? // BTW, why do you need to redraw it? Why Tikz?

Comment: @MS-SPO Yes flare attempts are too bad to be shown and also i'm very unsatisfied by the Corona. I redraw it because i want everyone one the web to have access to the original code to translate and improve it (i tried to modify the SVG of wikipedia to add temperatures and remove the black background but i failed).

Comment: Ok. As comments here aren‘t meant for discussion I suggest to add your interesting critics to your question. It would be good if you‘d line out how better drawings of the different components should look like from a physics point of view. E.g. you could explain a little, how temperature should translate into a visual effect. Thanks

Comment: TikZ is not really suitable for this kind of picture. There are no effects as ray trace, blur, smear and other stuff found in pixel based image programs. You clearly did make an attempt and it looks good. The problem now and the reason for the downvote as I see it, is that there is no clear goal to achieve - the goal is "make it look better", but *how*?

Comment: Please make your code compilable. And please link to the Wikipedia image, with credit, if that's appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,100}{
\draw[orange, opacity=0.1, line width=15pt] (0,0) -- ([shift={(360*rnd:0.9*rnd)}]45:3); \draw (0,0);
}
\foreach \i in {0,...,100}{
\draw[orange, opacity=0.1, line width=15pt] (0,0) -- ([shift={(360*rnd:0.8*rnd)}]-30:2.5); \draw (0,0);
}
\foreach \i in {0,...,100}{
\draw[orange, opacity=0.04, line width=15pt] (0,0) -- ([shift={(360*rnd:0.4*rnd)}]110:3.5); \draw (0,0);
}
\foreach \i in {0,...,100}{
\draw[orange, opacity=0.04, line width=15pt] (0,0) -- ([shift={(360*rnd:0.4*rnd)}]-110:3.5); \draw (0,0);
}
\foreach \i in {0,...,100}{
\draw[orange, opacity=0.04, line width=15pt] (0,0) -- ([shift={(360*rnd:0.6*rnd)}]-170:3); \draw (0,0);
}
\fill (0,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Black circle with radial orange flares]

Comment: The reason for `\draw (0,0)` is to prevent the lines ending in the same `transparency group` - possibly a bug in TikZ.

Comment: Just found that it is a bug in the mac preview of the pdf.